# error in running the rolled back migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and I am working on an existing project. I had created some new migrations, then I wanted to rollback to edit them and migrate again. I made a mistake and rolled back with 1 step more than the migrations I had done. Now that I try to use `rake db:migrate`, it gives an error about the migration that was existing and I have rolledback by mistake. The error is about `remove_column` statement, and it says that a column does not exist, so it can't remove it. But before when I was doing `rake db:migrate`, before I created migrations myself, there was not such an error. For info, I would like to say that I have not done any thing related to that table.

Could you please help?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: That column got removed when you executed you rollback and after that your rollback got interupted. Hence it was not finished. Just try to fix it via commenting out that particular remove_column migration. And do rollback again. And after that run migrate again.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. But when I run rollback, shouldn't it do the opposite of remove_column? I mean shouldn't it create that column again, so when I run the migrate again, it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the migration for removing the column, migrate the database and create new migration to remove the column.

If you edited the existed migration, comment out the line `remove_column`, run `rake db:migrate`, uncomment it back and run `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did based on second part of your answer. It also worked, but I have a question. When I uncomment and run the rake db:migrate, there is no message, which I think is natural. Because rails have the track of all the migrations and will not execute them again. So uncommenting should not do anything. Right?